# MVVM view only updating when data set in viewmodel's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm assuming this is probably an easy one, but I'm stuck.  I have a combobox whose data I can update within the constructor of the viewmodel, but I cannot get the view to update if I set the data after the viewmodel has been initialized.  I assume this either has something to do with my DataContext or my event-broadcasting, but I'm either missing something or not understanding something.

Additionally, I get a binding path error related to my 'DataPane' property, saying that it cannot be found in RedViewModel.  The console stops complaining if I place a property definition for DataPane in RedViewModel, but the code works in both scenarios.  DataPane is the DataContext for my MainView, not my RedView, so I'm not really sure why that is.  This may or may not be relevant background information; I'm mostly interested in the first part of this question.

Here's my XAML so far:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TableBuilder.Views.RedView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TableBuilder.Views"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TableBuilder.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:RedViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel Background="Red">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Type:" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Enumeration" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Value:" Grid.Column="1" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding EnumValueItems}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Units:" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Integer" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Description:" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="text" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using TableBuilder.Helpers;
using TableBuilder.Models;

namespace TableBuilder.ViewModels
{
    public class RedViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private object _dataPane;
        public object DataPane
        {
            get { return _dataPane; }
            private set
            {
                _dataPane = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataPane));
            }
        }
        private ListCollectionView _enumValueItems;
        public ListCollectionView EnumValueItems
        {
            get { return _enumValueItems;  }
            set
            {
                _enumValueItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnumValueItems));
            }
        }
        public bool Loaded { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _listData;

        public ObservableCollection<string> ListData
        {
            get { return _listData; }
            set
            {
                _listData = value;
                EnumValueItems = new ListCollectionView(ListData);
                //EnumValueItems.MoveCurrentTo(ListData[0]);
                //OnPropertyChanged("ListData");
            }
        } 

        public RedViewModel()
        {
            //_listData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            //EnumValueItems = new ListCollectionView(_listData);
            //EnumValueItems.CurrentChanged += enumValueItems_CurrentChanged;
            //GetListData();
        }
        public void GetListData()
        {
            ListData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            RedModel model = new RedModel();
            ListData = model.GetListData();
            //EnumValueItems = new ListCollectionView(model.GetListData());
            //EnumValueItems.MoveCurrentTo(ListData[0]);
            //EnumValueItems.CurrentChanged += EnumValueItems_CurrentChanged;
        }

        private void EnumValueItems_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Loaded)
            {
                MessageBox.Show((((ListCollectionView)sender).CurrentItem).ToString());
            }
            Loaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModelBase class is here:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using TableBuilder.Models;
using TableBuilder.ViewModels;

namespace TableBuilder.Helpers
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Here's the test code I'm using to try to modify the list data:

```
        public MainViewModel()
    {
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteOpen);
        ExitCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteExit);
        var vm = new RedViewModel();
        var test = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        test.Add("Test1");
        test.Add("Test2");
        test.Add("Test3");
        test.Add("Test4");
        test.Add("Test5");
        test.Add("Test6");
        test.Add("Test7");
        vm.EnumValueItems.Clear();
        foreach (string s in test) { vm.EnumValueItems.Add(s); }
        DataPane = vm;
    }
```

I assume I'm likely breaking the data binding in here somehow.

**Edit 2:**

To provide further context and clarity for the question, here is the general architecture of this program (be it for better or worse):

This program is a specialized-XML parser that is used to create config tables for embedded software based on an XML definition.  The Right side of the screen displays the relevant parts of the XML data based on the tree node the user has selected.  There are various views that are to be displayed on the left, pending whether the user has selected a variable that is an enum/float32/struct/etc.  The code I am interested in now is the Enum view, so there is a dropdown menu that is to be populated with the possible enum values based on the XML definition.

What I am trying to do, is populate the dropdown menu in RedViewModel (which will become my enum viewer on cleanup once I get everything working as intended) from the MainViewModel.  If I populate the list in the RedViewModel's constructor, it appears to properly display.  However, if I populate it anywhere else (in the example I provided, I populated it in MainViewModel's constructor after RedViewModel was instantiated), it doesn't appear to update.

Comment: What data do you set "after the viewmodel has been initialized" and where do you set it in your code?

Comment: I've updated the original post to include my test code.

Comment: You have posted the constructor of the view model...? So what do you mean by  "after the viewmodel has been initialized"? Where are you instatiating the MainViewModel and where are you binding to DataPane? Please clarify your question and provide a minimal sample of your issue.

Comment: I updated the original question.  In short, there are multiple view models.  If I update the data in RedViewModel's constructor, it works fine.  In the above example, I tried to instantiate RedViewModel and then set its data.  I was testing it in the constructor of another view model because it was easy to see if it was working there.  The RedView does properly display, but the contents of my dropdown menu are empty when created in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding to `EnumValueItems` is only notified *of a change* when the *reference* to the list changes, not when items are added or removed from the list.

To keep with the current system, unassign the reference to a new list and the control will change to the new list thanks to `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of this quirk.  To make sure I understand you correctly, I DO want to create a new EnumValueItems then? (as opposed to the previous answers)

Comment: Yes, create a temporary list, fill it, then assign the list to `EnumValueItems`. I have done it / do it to update controls. Now if this occurs frequently, you may want to look into the `ObservableCollection` which does send out notifications when add to or remove from actions occur within the list.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original comment, because I had changed my code to use ObservableCollection instead of ListCollectionView.  Which still doesn't seem to update the list.  I kind of thought this was going to be an easier question than it is, and I've exhausted as many tutorials and references as I could get my hands on.  Any tips for debugging something like this?  It IS sending the update, but the UI is not responding.

Comment: Just do a `List<string>` instead. Keep the binding and do the change I suggested; to try. The `View` thing is off.

Comment: See my blog MVVM Binding Strategy [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)
to see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, I did find my answer on your blog page! I had statically-set my viewmodel in XAML, which created all of the problems I was seeing.  Great blog by the way; I've bookmarked it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a new value to `EnumValueItems` will break the binding. Instead you should be binding to an `ObservableCollection`. Then clear the items and add them from the other collection when changing.

Instead of:

```
EnumValueItems = NewCollectionView
```

Try this (after changing to `ObservableCollection`):

```
EnumValueItems.Clear();
foreach (ObjectType ob in NewCollection) {EnumValueItems.Add(ob);}
```

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: Good catch.  It didn't seem to solve my problem, though your solution does make sense.  I've updated the original post to include the code I'm using to try to call this; maybe there's something incorrect there.